# ruby on rails get table row by two column conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, database-design

For instance, I have two tables in database, Users and Microposts. The Users table stores all the users and has two columns, id and name; the Microposts table stores the posts made by the Users and has three columns: id, post_content and user_id (These two tables, of course, have the timestamp as each entry is created). So basically what I want is have a view page that displays the information stored in Users (id and name) plus the last post created by the corresponding user.
One way I'm thinking of doing is to have it being processed right at the user view page (located in, for example, app/views/Users/index.html.erb). Since I'm probably going to loop through the Users table like this

```
<% @Users.each do |user| %>
    id = user.id
    <!-- Do such and such -->
<% end %>
```

and while looping through the Users table, use the user.id to get the latest post made by the user.

Second way is to basically implement such that the Users table has another column that store the latest post information and updates each time when a transaction is made to the database. So then when implementing the latest post can just be accessed as an attribute.

However, I don't really know which way is better nor how to implement either way...
Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance!

---

Edit:
Sorry, there is a typo. It's "two tables and one database"

Comment: Why you are using two DATABASES,.. !!!!!

Comment: If you are using one DATABASE and 2 TABLES, Its very simple to implement. Then You use table relations.

Comment: Use your first implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the other answers but I wanted to add an important little piece that I feel is commonly overlooked. Including the association on the first call to the database.

```
# not sure the scale of your project but I would paginate @users
# by using includes you prevent the N+1 issues
<% @users.includes(:microposts).each do |user| %>
    id = user.id
    user.microposts.last
<% end %>
```

For some documentation on this:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: Your welcome! It should also be noted that it is best to put the includes() part in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class User 
        has_many :microposts
    end

    class Micropost
        belong_to :user
    end

   # to get user's post 
   # for single user
    @user.microposts
   # for many users
    @users.each do |user|
        user.microposts.each  do  |post|
            post.post_content
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your user has many microposts. So do the following on users view page i.e. app/views/Users/index.html.erb

```
<% @Users.each do |user| %>
    id = user.id
    last_post = user.microposts.last <!-- This will give you last post created by the user -->
<% end %>
```